# CSS button effects

Tags: html, css

[Demo](http://codepen.io/GopsAB/pen/NqRpYo)

```
  .common_button:active
  {
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px -2px #777;
    padding: 3px;
    width:80px;
  }

  .common_button_container
  {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 7px;
  }
```

I am trying to create button-pressing effects. But I don't want this effect to affect it's container. i want to have only width and height reduced on button while pressing but not for the container. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just hard set the height of the `.common_button_container` by adding `height: 30px;` to it.

Comment: and using `box-sizing:border-box`. Oh...and `[**Links/Divs are not buttons**](http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/)

Answer (score 0):

If the size of the container is not specified, use this:

```css
.common_button_placeholder
  {
  background-color: transparent;
    color: transparent;
  }

.common_button
  {
  position: absolute;
  }

.common_button:active
  {
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px -2px #777;
    padding: 3px;
    width:80px;
  }

  .common_button_container
  {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 7px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="common_button_container">
  <div class="common_button">Submit</div>
  <div class="common_button_placeholder">Submit</div>
</div>
```

The `common_button` is set to `absolute`; `common_button_placeholder` not. So `common_button_placeholder` is behind the orginal, it set the size of the container, but `common_button` has no further effect to it.
Just for the styling, how about using `transition`:

```
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
```